# Font Formatting in Advanced Label Expression ArcGIS/Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, font

Almost have this quandry figured out, but inevitably a new problem has popped up. I finally have the "code" part down to do what I want, but now the font formatting isn't acting properly. When I use a simple expression with font tags I can create this image.
[image]

However, when I use the advanced expression as follows, it returns the garbled image after. I'm using the tags the same way and can't find any reason they shouldn't be working. Without quotes I get a syntax error. EDIT - Trimmed code to focus on issue area. Font tags were improperly placed, see answer 1.

```
if float([Percentage_Complete]) >= 90:
lab1 =  "<bol><clr green='255'>" + lab1 + "</bol></clr>\n"
if float([Percentage_Complete1]) >= 90:
lab2 =  "<bol><clr green='255'>" +  lab2 +  "</bol></clr>\n"
if float([Percentage_Complete2]) >= 90:
lab3 =  "<bol><clr green='255'>"+  lab3 + "</bol></clr>\n"
if float([Percentage_Complete3]) >= 90:
lab4 =  "<bol><clr green='255'>"+  lab4+  "</bol></clr>\n"
```

[image]

Comment: I found that it might need to use the & operator to concatenate, but I get a syntax error with that as well around the lab1, etc.

Comment: Try enclosing them in one more set of quotations

Comment: I get the logic, but gives me a syntax error. And that would have been ridiculous if that was necessary to make that work. Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: After your if statements they should also be indented

Comment: Yeah, that was just a copy paste thing I didn't want to bother correcting. The code is now sound(I think), its just the format tags don't want to play nice.

Comment: Also what is the point of defining "highlight" and "endhigh" if you're not using those variables? 
Perhaps it should look more like `lab2 = highlight + lab2 + endhigh`

Comment: Yeah, some of that is just troubleshooting leftovers. I had that initially and it wasn't working. Tried some breakdown, if I remove the + lab1 + lab2 + lab3 + lab4, header parts work fine. If I add any back into the label var, it freaks out.

Comment: I would remove any superfluous code when trying to troubleshoot. Is SQL queries out of the question for you? Or Exporting the a selection that is >90?

Comment: No on the SQL queries that I can see. I tried that first and I'm not sure if it was because of the number of variables, but i didn't see that it actually did anything.

Comment: I wonder if the / in your dates or perhaps the _ is causing the problem.  When I've done similar things in the past, I know having an & in any of the fields I am using will cause my expression not to work.

Comment: I know I don't have any & in the date ranges or anything and again, if I print just the header portion [SWSID] and [Stn_Name] they come out just fine. Just when adding the other vars on it screw up. Going to try writing it all out into the if statements.

Comment: UPDATE - Nope that doesn't work either, still sees the tags as strings

Comment: Narrowed further, its a problem with the color tag. Working on a fix

Comment: You have the bol and clr tags end tags in the wrong order. It should be `<bol><clr green='255'>"+  lab4+  "</clr></bol>\n"` for each of them.

Comment: My goodness that is frustrating, but I figured it out right about when you posted. How silly. Thank you kenbuja!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This was determined to be the issue to this problem. It will be marked as the answer soon.* When using format tags make sure they close from inside out. Thanks to @kenbuja for clarifying that.

```
"<bol><clr green='255'>"+lab4+"</clr></bol>"

NOT "<bol><clr green='255'>"+lab4+"</bol></clr>"
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit your answer to state clearly that it does answer your question, please?  Also, so others do not have to go through the same pain perhaps you can simplify your question to just the parts that in hindsight were causing all the problem so that a cleaner Q&A results?

Comment: Sure I can do that, I tried to mark it as the answer, but said I had to wait two days. But I'll clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

This works to simply bold text and include a new line:

```
"<bol>" + [PointID] + "</bol>" + "\n" + [Structype]
```

to get

**6438**
Manhole

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question, how you set green color if the number is greater than 90?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ampersand as you suggested and use vbcrlf instead of \n. I don't think \n works

"**" + [PARCEL] & vbcrlf & "TEXT" & "**"
something like this

Comment: If it matters, the error I get with the & indicates a problem between 'str' and 'unicode'. I assume the unicode is my variable name lab1, lab2, etc. Oh, and I thought I mentioned it, but guess not, this is for Python not VB

Comment: can you convert the unicode in the attributes ? Something like str(lab1) ?

Comment: Yes I suppose I wasn't thinking about the code you had there. I was thinking it was code you put in an expression. It wouldn't be easy to redo it if it were a script. Still I can run the str() python function on my attributes and it works.

Comment: Another good thought, but no go.

Comment: It is code I put directly into the advanced expression box in the label properties under the Python parser.

Comment: I'm surprised that something like this wouldn't work. It works for me when I replace your fields with mine.
lab1 = "T_avg  " + str([First_Date_In_DB]) + "  " + str([Last_Date_In_DB]) + "  " + str([Percentage_Complete]) + "\n"

Comment: I just tried it on it's own and mine still prints with the tags.